# ChromeOptions when WebDriver is instantiated globally - Selenium Webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options

I have a project I'm working on with several test methods. I need WebDriver to be available globally after I instantiate it and with ChromeOptions.

I'm using a @Before annotation to do a lot of setup and I thought I could pass ChromeOptions into the webdriver which is instantiated globally. 'options.addArguments()' isn't available globally and it isn't recognizing my options. Example below:

```
     public class classThatDoesStuff_Test {
        private static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
        @Before
        public void setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\SeleniumWorkspace\\ABC\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless=new");
        options.addArguments("--window-size-1400,800");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        }
        
        public void doStuff() {
        driver.get("http://foo.bar.com");
        
        }
```

Running this does not start the browser headless.

I tried creating a method with ChromeOptions and passing it to the driver. That didn't work

```
private static ChromeOptions options() {
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--headless=new");
            options.addArguments("window-size=1400,800");
            options.addArguments("disable-gpu");
            
            return options;
```

Then passing it to my instantiation. But that didn't work - as you probably guessed :)

Comment: You have to pass the options in when you create the driver.  ex: new ChromeDriver(options);  Add the new ChromeDriver call to the end of the setup method so you can use the options.  So private static WebDriver driver;  then driver = new ChromeDriver(options) after creating the options.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\TestUser\\Desktop\\SeleniumWorkspace\\ABC\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*", "ignore-certificate-errors");
    options.addArguments("--headless=new");
    options.addArguments("--window-size-1400,800");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // missing to pass chrome options here

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).